# Android Studio Dolphin (Kotlin) : App crashes when launching

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I tried creating a simple database in which i can add a product. delete products, and search.
I followed a tutorial on a book as i am a beginner in kotlin and android studio.

Here is the Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RoomDemo"

        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my main activity :

```
package com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.ui.main.MainFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

here is the fragmentmain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/product_id"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_not_assigned"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/not_assigned"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/product_name"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/productName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/product_quantity"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/productQuantity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/findButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Find"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:baselineAligned="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, here is the logcat (only errors) :

```
2023-01-18 20:14:36.108 1950-1950/com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo, PID: 1950
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo/com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.ui.main.MainFragment.getBinding(MainFragment.kt:32)
        at com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.ui.main.MainFragment.listenerSetup(MainFragment.kt:65)
        at com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.ui.main.MainFragment.onCreate(MainFragment.kt:44)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2981)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:474)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1670)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
        at com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8269)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

as requested, here is the mainFragment file:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.ProductRepository
import com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.MainActivity
import com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.ProductDao
import com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.ui.main.ProductListAdapter
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.R
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.Product
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import java.util.*
import com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.databinding.FragmentMainBinding

//preparation du main fragment
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private var adapter: ProductListAdapter? = null

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }

    val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
    private var _binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    // si ya une erreur c'est ici
    private fun recyclerSetup(){
        adapter = ProductListAdapter(R.layout.product_list_item)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        listenerSetup()
        observerSetup()
        recyclerSetup()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun clearFields() {
        binding.productID.text = ""
        binding.productName.setText("")
        binding.productQuantity.setText("")
    }

    //ajout de bouton listeners
    private fun listenerSetup() {
        binding.addButton.setOnClickListener {
            val name = binding.productName.text.toString()
            val quantity = binding.productQuantity.text.toString()

            if (name != "" && quantity != "") {
                val product = Product(name, Integer.parseInt(quantity))
                viewModel.insertProduct(product)
                clearFields()
            } else {
                binding.productID.text = " Infos Incompletes "
            }
        }
        binding.findButton.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.findProduct(binding.productName.text.toString())
        }


        binding.deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.deleteProduct(
                binding.productName.text.toString()
            )
            clearFields()
        }

    }

    private fun observerSetup() {
        viewModel.getAllProducts()
            ?.observe(this, Observer { products -> products?.let { adapter?.setProductList(it) } })
        viewModel.getSearchResults().observe(this, Observer { products ->
            products?.let {
                if(it.isNotEmpty()){
                    binding.productID.text = String .format(Locale.US, "%d", it[0].id)
                    binding.productName.setText(it[0].productName)
                    binding.productQuantity.setText(String.format(Locale.US,"%d",it[0].quantity))
                }
                else {
                    binding.productID.text = "No Match"
                }
            }
        })
    }






}
```

Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me !

i just tried to run the app on the android studio emulator and it displayed an error message saying : "RoomDemo keeps stoping" right after i launched the app. RoomDemo is the name of my app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be seen in the logcat extract.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        
at com.ebookfrenzy.roomdemo.ui.main.MainFragment.getBinding(MainFragment.kt:32)
```

This makes it look like `getBinding` returns null at line 32 in MainFragment. You didn't post the code for `MainFragment`. Add this to the question for further assistance.

EDIT : Adding further information below now that MainFragment has been added to the question.

In `onCreate` you are doing things that will try to use the `binding`. But the `binding` hasn't been assigned yet, this happens inside `onCreateView`.

There is a lifecycle method for `onViewCreated` which will be called after `onCreateView` has returned. You can guarantee at this point binding will have been assigned and so invoking the various functions that are called inside `onCreate` in `onViewCreated` will prevent the null pointer exception.

You should read up on android lifecycle for an [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), and [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle). This will help you understand why you had the problem.

Comment: Hi Chris, i uploaded my MainFragment in the question. I read the logcat, and as a beginner i tried searching on the net before asking for help here of course, but i couldn't find anything understandable for me... thank you for your reply !